Get shopify customers' data into Google sheet using Google Apps Script
I am trying to get customer's data from shopify but cannot find one parameter in the API response. Following is the screenshot:

I want to get the value June 6,7,8 enclosed in Green. Here is the code snippet that I am using:
function getShopifyData() {
  var url = "https://your-shopify-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/customers.json";
  var username = "###"; // API Key
  var password = "###"; // Access Token
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
    }
  });

  var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log(jsonData);
}

The JSON response looks like this, however I could not find date June 6,7,8:
[ { id: 83105908183,
       email: 'mail',
       created_at: '2024-05-24T14:45:04+08:00',
       updated_at: '2024-05-24T14:45:04+08:00',
       first_name: 'name',
       last_name: 'name2',
       orders_count: 0,
       state: 'disabled',
       total_spent: '0.00',
       last_order_id: null,
       note: null,
       verified_email: true,
       multipass_identifier: null,
       tax_exempt: false,
       tags: '',
       last_order_name: null,
       currency: 'AUD',
       phone: null,
       addresses: [Object],
       tax_exemptions: [],
       email_marketing_consent: [Object],
       sms_marketing_consent: null,
       admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/Customer/83105908183',
       default_address: [Object] }]

I would really appreciate if you could guide me to get this field.

Looks like metadata. Is the data even present in your json? You might have to use the official graphql api

I am not entirely sure where this information is, but I have two ideas:

is the information even contained in the customers.json? Could it be related to a different entity?

what exactly the info is related to, e.g. might be part of a nested object returned by the json and should be accessed as an object property
eg:
  jsonData.forEach(function(customer) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2));
  if (customer.addresses) {
    console.log("Addresses: " + JSON.stringify(customer.addresses, null, 2));
  }
  if (customer.email_marketing_consent) {
    console.log("Email Marketing Consent: " + JSON.stringify(customer.email_marketing_consent, null, 2));
  }
  if (customer.default_address) {
    console.log("Default Address: " + JSON.stringify(customer.default_address, null, 2));
  }
});



My 2 cents.
